# Extract Bash output to a CSV File for Plotting

Tags: bash

I am trying to measure the time it takes for a Kubernetes object to be deployed in a Kubernetes cluster by using the `time` utility. I am trying to do that severally with a time sleep to get values for multiple simulation of deployments.

**This is the script.**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function time_check {
    i=$1
    time kubectl apply -f deploy.yml --dry-run=client
}

for i in {1..3}
do 
    time_check $i &
    sleep 2
done
```

**This is the Output**

```bash
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    0m0.421s
user    0m0.359s
sys     0m0.138s
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    0m0.359s
user    0m0.443s
sys     0m0.158s
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    0m0.138s
user    0m0.412s
sys     0m0.122s
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    1.483s
user    0m0.412s
sys     0m0.122s
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    1.456s
user    0m0.234s
sys     0m0.567s
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)

real    2.345
user    0m0.435s
sys     0m0.123s
```

**Goal**

I want to pipe the output and take the first row of each iteration's `real 0m0.421s` , Then take the number part `0m0.421s` and strip the `0m` if it's in seconds or just leave it if it's in minutes like `1.483`. Also strip the `s` at the end

The final results should be output in a CSV file to be plotted. The expected output in CSV

```bash
real
0.421
0.359
0.138
1.483
1.456
2.345
```

**Add-on**

I will do this for another deployment and plot the two `times` data in a line graph to see the time it takes for each deployment

Comment: I'm assuming that's a typo ... `time_check i$ &` should be `time_check $i &`; could you update the sample timings (and expected results) to demonstrate how you want to process timings that are not of the form `0m0.???s`, especially if you have a mix of formats (eg, if you have a mix of seconds and minutes do all results need to be converted to seconds)?

Comment: Hey, @markp-fuso I have updated it to `$i`. I have also updated the sample timings. The first three with format `0m0.???s` and the last three with format `1.???`

Comment: There is a general conflict with var `i`. The function overrides the global `i`.  Here it doesn't matter, because the assignment is `i=i`. Use always `local` for local vars, and here `local i=$1`.

Comment: Hey, @Wiimm Thanks. If you can take a look at this comment of mine down here:
Sending the output to a CSV like this grep -v deployment | tr '\n' ',' >> file.csv gives an empty file being created. Nothing inside of it

Comment: Can you clarify the bit on **Goals**? Are you stripping units, but not standardizing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the shell builtin command time.  If you switch to linux's time command you can control the output and get the just the data you want.

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f  '%e' sleep 1.5
1.50
```

see `man time` for more details

you can take the output and pipe it into  `grep -v deployment | tr '\n' ','` that will strip the dry run lines, and convert the renaming newlines into commas

```
$ printf "1\njunk\n2\njunk\n3\n" 
1
junk
2
junk
3
$ printf "1\njunk\n2\njunk\n3\n" | grep -v junk | tr '\n' ','
1,2,3, $
```

this is a quick and dirty way to slice the date.  I'm sure there are other solutions as well.

Comment: Hey @toppk. Your solution gets me half way. However it outputs it with the command like ```deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)
0.46
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)
0.38
deployment.apps/nginx-raw created (dry run)
0.39
```
However, if I could get only those values sent to a CSV file

Comment: you can take the output and pipe it into ` grep -v deployment | tr '\n' ','`  that will strip the dry run lines, and convert the renaming newlines into commas.

Comment: Awesome! That works well. However, sending the output to a CSV like this `grep -v deployment | tr '\n' ',' >> file.csv` gives an empty file being created. Nothing inside of it

Answer (score 0):

I just used a randomized sub-second sleep to get the output stream, but the principle should work.

```
$: for x in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do time sleep 0.$RANDOM; done 2>&1 | 
>    awk 'BEGIN{print "real"}/^real/{ print gensub(/^.*m([0-9.]+)s/,"\\1",1)}'
real
0.266
0.716
0.847
0.251
0.358
0.236
0.669
0.266
0.308
0.856
```

Explained a bit with inline comments -

```
$: for x in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do # this is just a dump loop
     time sleep 0.$RANDOM           # create some output 
   done 2>&1 |                      # dup time output stderr -> stdout
>    awk >my.csv 'BEGIN{print "real"} # the header
          /^real/{ # match for the lines we want (ignore the rest)
             print gensub(/^.*m([0-9.]+)s/,"\\1",1) #  just print matched part
          }'
```

## separate issue

> I want to pipe the output and take the first row of each iteration's real 0m0.421s , Then take the number part 0m0.421s and strip the 0m if it's in seconds or just leave it if it's in minutes like 1.483. Also strip the s at the end

So what you are saying is that if it takes 1.5 seconds you want it to output `1.500`, but if it takes 90.0 seconds you want it to output `1.500`.

How will you tell which it is without either specifying units or *standardizing* units?

Comment: Hey @Paul Hodges
Can you pipe the output to a file like a CSV to be plotted in an excel sheet

Comment: Just add `>my.csv` after the awk? Am I missing something? For the record, most people put it at the end, but it doesn't technically have to be.